# How to get authorization token for MIPSDK's ImageServer

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, soap-client

I want to connect to the Management server of milestone sdk (MIPSDK) and get the token for MIPSDK's imageServer. I am using sockets but could not figure out how to do it.
This is what i have done so far

```
import ssl

import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect(('192.168.x.xx', 443))

s = ssl.wrap_socket(s, keyfile=None, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE, certfile=None, server_side=False, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
s.settimeout(10);


s.sendall("POST /ManagementServer/ServerCommandService.svc HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.xx.xx\r\nAuthorization:Basic\ xxxxxx\r\nContent-Length: 2048\r\n\r\n")

new = s.recv(4096)
print new
```

Is that even possible to Login to Management server from python client?
There are build in classes/functionalities in DotNet but I am unable to find out any python implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around I have finally managed to get the token from milestone imageServer.

```
import ssl
import socket
import uuid

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('server-ip', 443))
v = uuid.uuid4()
s = ssl.wrap_socket(s, keyfile=None, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE, certfile=None, server_side=False, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
data= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><Login xmlns="http://videoos.net/2/XProtectCSServerCommand"><instanceId>' + str(v) + '</instanceId><currentToken></currentToken></Login></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'
data_len = len(data)
data_len = str(data_len)
s.sendall("POST /ManagementServer/ServerCommandService.svc HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: server-ip\r\nContent-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\nAuthorization: Basic (base64 of '[BASIC]\username:password')\r\nContent-Length: "+data_len+"\r\nSOAPAction: http://videoos.net/2/XProtectCSServerCommand/IServerCommandService/Login\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" + data)

while True:
    new = s.recv(4096)
    if not new:
        s.close()
        break
    print(new)
```

I am using basic authentication.